# How can I retriever the number of DISTINCT projects in one table to store a boolean for each user and each project in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for project announcements with the structure -

```
**Announcements Table**

| ---------- | ----------------- |
|  Project   |   Announcement    | 
| ---------- | ----------------- | 
|  [String]  |    [String]       |
| ---------- | ----------------- |
```

I want to allow users to subscribe to projects they would like to receive announcements for so that they may receive these announcements by email. Therein lies my problem.

I could structure the database as follows -

```
**Subscription Table**

| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | 
|  Name      |  Email     |  Project1  |  Project2  |  Project3  |  ...etc... | 
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | 
| [String]   | [String]   | [Boolean]  | [Boolean]  | [Boolean]  | [Boolean]  |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
```

with a Boolean representing whether or not each user is subscribed to each project.

This has the advantage of being a simple structure, however the disadvantage that any new projects would have to be added manually. This should not be terribly difficult because there are only likely to be <4 new projects per year added to the Announcements table, though obviously it is not ideal.

Obviously to get the number of distinct projects in the announcements table DISTINCT or GROUP BY could be used. But I am not sure how to use this in order to store data / generate data for the second table.

Comment: (Apologies if this is badly worded, I am very new to databases which is why I am struggling with what may potentially be a simple problem. I am very eager to edit to improve wording if that is helpful. Thank you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really shouldn't be doing that. Having a list of boolean columns will give you problems... a lot of problems. As projects change over time, you will have to do maintenance on the table and it will be hell.

If you want to start with a good normalized structure, you should look at something like this:

**Users**

```
id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
Name  VARCHAR
email VARCHAR
```

**Projects**

```
id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
Name VARCHAR
```

**Annoucements**

```
id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
project_id INTEGER REFERENCES Projects (id)
text       VARCHAR
```

**Subscriptions**

```
user_id    INTEGER REFERENCS Users (id)
project_id INTEGER REFERENCES Projects (id)
```

with a UNIQUE or PRIMARY key on user_id, project_id

This is how you should handle many-to-many relations. No structure changes are required when you need a new project. It is all reduced to adding or removing rows from one or more tables... **rows, not columns**.

For example... if you want a list of all annoucements that users have subscribed to:

```
SELECT u.Name, u.email, p.Name, a.text
FROM subscriptions s
JOIN users         u ON u.id=s.user_id
JOIN projects      p ON p.id=s.project_id
JOIN annoucements  a ON a.project_id=s.project_id
```

---

Separating Projects from Announcements is not necessary, but I do advise it. If you have few projects and many announcements, or if you have different people managing projects and annoucements, then you should definitely use 2 different tables. Using a VARCHAR column to identify groups of rows is not a good habit for various reasons (spelling mistakes, upper/lower case). Your foreign keys should always be field the user knows nothing about and will **never** want to change.

If you ever want to change a project name, you will have to do it massively. If you ever want to add other info concerning projects, you cannot do it on the annoucements table without duplicating data... which is not a good thing... and will bring integrity problems sooner or later.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain in a little more detail how these would interact to achieve what I am trying to do? 

I think I get the idea in general however more detail would be very helpful.

Comment: I assume, for instance, if I wanted to retrieve each users subscriptions I would simply look for `User` in the `Subscriptions` table and see what they are subscribed to?

Comment: The query I added list all annoucements of all users... you can add a WHERE clause to filter out on any column of any of the 4 tables envolved... user id, or maybe an annoucement date, or a project id.

Comment: Is there a reason to have `Projects` and `Announcements` as separate tables rather than doing `GROUP BY` to determine unique Projects?

Comment: Do `Projects` and `Announcements` mean the same thing? Are they interchangeable including all of their aspects and related data (including data stored in depending and referenced tables)? If any of your answers are `NO`, then you should separate them. If all of the answers are `YES`, then you can not talk about two things, they are the same and you should use a unique name for them.

Comment: @Eilidh `Project` and `Announcements` should be separated to avoid to repeat the `Projects` information. There is a good probability you'll have multiple announcements for each project if you'll put them in the `Projects` table you'll have to use `GROUP` every time you need to get data about projects, for example if you need to get the list of users subscribed to a project.

Comment: @Pred Is there anywhere you would recommend where I could look for more information on the subject of appropriate table design so that I can avoid issues like this in the future? Databases are all new to me but I have responsibility for a rather large one now and your responses made me realise there are serious issues with the structure of its main table. I'm doing a restructure of it very soon and I'd like to incorporate these principles as obviously they are valuable (as you have explained) - is there a resource you'd recommend to learn more? Thank you

Comment: @Eilidh Huhh, this is a harder question than your original :) I can not suggest you specific sites or books, but here are some keywords to search for: `Conceptual Database Design`, `Logical Database Design`, `Entity Model`, `Requirement Analysis`, `Normal Forms` You will find more keywords, concepts and tools while reading, understand those too. **But first of all, you have to understand your data before you are trying to design a database to store it**